Loop through child views created dynamically in android view
I have a view where I have added several EditText views dynamically and I need to loop through the views to capture any data entered.  I've looked at this solution on StackOverflow:
public void recursiveLoopChildren(ViewGroup parent) {
        for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
            final View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
            if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
                recursiveLoopChildren((ViewGroup) child);
                // DO SOMETHING WITH VIEWGROUP, AFTER CHILDREN HAS BEEN LOOPED
            } else {
                if (child != null) {
                    // DO SOMETHING WITH VIEW
                }
            }
        }
    }

But this doesn't work because ViewGroup does not contain a method GetChildCount().  I've looked at the definition for ViewGroup and View and neither one has a "count" or "getchildcount" method or property.  Is there a way to loop through the child views of a view?

Well, neither ViewGroup or View have a child count, but LinearLayout does.  Given that, I was able to get it done.
This is my Layout:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="34.4dp">
            <Button
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:background="@color/colorGold"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/saveChange"
                android:id="@+id/btnSave" />
      </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="0sp"
        android:background="#000000" />
    <ImageView
        android:contentDescription="Participant's Photo"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/imageview_participant"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0.0dp" />
    <TextView
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/TextView_name" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="230dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/ageasof"
            android:text="@string/ageAsOf" />
        <TextView
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/age"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="0sp"
        android:background="#000000" />
    <TextView
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/AdditionalData" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/listlayout">
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

As you can see I have three LinearLayouts of which only one (listlayout) has the subviews I'm looking for because they are added to the listlayout LinearLayout at run time. I am able to loop through each of the LinearLayouts and access the EditTexts contained within.  I use a button click to save the data.
My code:
btnSave.Click += (sender, e) =>
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list.ChildCount; i++)
    {
        object MyObject = list.GetChildAt(i);
        if (MyObject.GetType() == typeof(LinearLayout))
        {
            LinearLayout MyLinearLayout = (LinearLayout)MyObject;
            for (int j= 0; j < MyLinearLayout.ChildCount; j++)
            {
                object MyObject2 = MyLinearLayout.GetChildAt(j);
                if (MyObject2.GetType() == typeof(EditText))
                {
                    EditText MyEditText = (EditText)MyObject2;
                    datainterface.SaveDataFieldData(MyUser.Username, MyUser.Password, fieldid, (string)MyEditText.Tag, MyEditText.Text);
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

I store the data field ID in the tag of the EditText so I can line up the data with the correct field when I retrieve it for edit.  And yes, I can optimize the code further, but wanted to post it as is so it is more readable.  In any event, works like a charm.
